# Typescript object indexer and key that doesn't match indexer type

Tags: javascript, typescript

The Typescript docs show the following example:

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number;
    length: number;    // ok, length is a number
    name: string;      // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```

What is the recommended workaround for the above example, e.g. I have an object that I know has a `name: string` property, and it can have any other possible keys, all of which must be numbers?

Comment: This is not possible, because `index` in your indexer might also be `name`.

Comment: What you are asking for is JavaScript. The point of TypeScript is to change the way code is written. If you want a more dynamic approach just stick with JS, or learn how to write your program with static types. This is really an issue of mindset. Honestly I would suggest reading a book about TS, not an academic pearson style, but something where the author discusses their personal relationship with TS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that such a type is inherently inconsistent. Consider the following code:

```
let prop = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "name" : "other"
let dic: NumberDictionary;
let value = dic[prop] // typed as number but could end up as string at run-time
```

The index definition tells us `number` but we might end up with `string` at runtime.

The honest thing to do is make the index signature return `number | string`.

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number | string;
    length: number;
    name: string;
}
let prop = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "name" : "other"
let dic: NumberDictionary;
let value = dic[prop] // typed as number | string we need a type guard to tell teh difference
```

The honest solution might not always be practical, and, being fully aware of the dangers, you can define an intersection type that will let you get away with the inconsistency:

```
type NumberDictionary = {
  [index: string]: number;
} & {
  length: number;    
  name: string;
}

let prop = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "neverName" : "other"
let dic: NumberDictionary = {
  name: "",
  length: 1
} as NumberDictionary; // type assertion necessary, ts will still complain here about the inconsistentcy 
let value = dic[prop] // typed as number, hope everyone avoids passing in name
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number | string;
    length: number;
    name: string;
}
```